# Avoid: To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous task in the componentWillUnmount method - REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native

Dont know how can I avoid this warning, tried many ways and it stills come out,

way 1:

create a flag `mounted`

```
mounted = false;

componentDidMount() {
 
 this.mounted = true;

}

componentWillUnMount() {
 
 this.mounted = false;

}

text = (text) => {
 
  this.moutend && this.setState({content: text});

}
```

way number 2 create a `aborController();`

```
abortController = newAbortController();

componentWillUnMount() {

 this.abortController.abort();

}
```

so, really dont know how to avoid it

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `mounted` inside your `constructor`

```
contructor(props){
     super(props)
     this.mounted = false
 }
```

Comment: constructor is now depecreated

Comment: Could you please try using only super()?

Comment: If you are using TypeScript  you can use `/** @param {Record<string, any>} props */` just above your constructor.